# what can we say about the solution of the equation $y'=-y^2$ just by looking at it. [without finding its solution]

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I trying to understand differential equations without finding their solution.

This is a simple one, so I can verify the ideas from the solution.

All ideas are appreciated, since they will help my understanding of DEs without solving them.

Answer (score 1):

The solution will be nonincreasing, because $y'\le 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Alse $y''=-2yy'=-2y(-y^2)=2y^3$.  So $y''$ at any point has the same sign as $y$.  So  $y$ is concave up when $y$ is positive; concave down when $y$ is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Derivative is negative, so it will be decreasing.

$y(t)=0$ satisfies the equation. The sign of $y(x)$ then needs to be constant, otherwise when you hit 0, you stay there.